# How to load index.php first on Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I have configured a website on a Windows Server 2008 R2 on APACHE24 and PHP.

It is working properly. But my problem is, it is not working on port 80.

It can be accessed by:

**12.X.X.X:3000/ors**

But what I want is it can be load by only entering the IP Address.

**12.X.X.X**

which I think it can be done by setting the port on the default 80.

When I change the Listen: and ServerName to 12.X.X.X:80 and try to load it says cannot connect to the IP.

Comment: What part of httpd.conf? I tried changing the Listen and Servername to 12.X.X.X:80 but that didn't work also.

Answer (score 1):

Open httpd.conf file. `apache->bin->httpd.conf` and edit the following line:

`<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex 
    php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>`

and restart server.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! but my configuration is actually set just like that.